# how to run the timer in background or calling the task at a specific place?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, timer, udp

```
int callBackTimers()
 {
     makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
         makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
         makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
         while(1)
             ;;
 }

int CreateSocket()
{


    socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
       // Socket creation for UDP

       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

       if(acceptSocket==-1)

       {

         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");

         return 1;

       }

       else

       {

         printf("Socket started!\n");

       }

       //non blocking mode
      /* rc = ioctl(acceptSocket, FIONBIO, (char *)&flag);
          if (rc < 0)
          {
                     printf("\n ioctl() failed \n");
             return 0;
          }*/

          //Bind the socket
     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

     addr.sin_port=htons(port);

     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));

     if(rc== -1)

     {

       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n");

       return 1;

     }

     else

     {

       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);

     }


     if(acceptSocket == -1)
     {
         printf("Fehler: accept, fehler code:\n");

          return 1;
     }
     else
     {

     while(rc!=-1)
         {


         rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }


         XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );
         callBackTimers();

          }


     }

       close(acceptSocket);



       return 0;

     }






int main()
{

     Xcp_Initialize();
     CreateSocket();
     return 1;

}
```

I am working on a client and server architecture. Server code is shown above and I created a socket to recieve the request from the client via the ip address and port number. Server is waiting for a request from the client and send a response back to the client. when ever it recieves data from the client, it should call the timer task, For that I also created timer to call the task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. when ever I recieved the data via the socket then the timer should be called (in my code callBackTimers). else it should be running in the background . How to do any  one of the task ?? If I do like above then when ever it recieves the data, the timer will be called.

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question (or at least a very similar question) multiple times? What was wrong with the answers you got earlier?

Comment: my question is different now!!! when it receives the data from the client then where to call the callBackTimers in my code ?